# I have two form to get email in my webpage but whenever i submit the form the message form is not valid is displayef

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('email-submit/form1/', views.email_submit, name='email-submit1'),
    path('email-submit/form2/', views.email_submit, name='email-submit2'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import EmailSubscription

class EmailSubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailSubscription
        fields = ['email']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class EmailSubscription(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import EmailSubscriptionForm

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'maincontent/home.html')


def about(request):
    form1 = EmailSubscriptionForm()
    form2 = EmailSubscriptionForm()
    return render(request, 'maincontent/about.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'maincontent/contact.html')

def email_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_id = request.POST.get('form_id')

        if form_id == 'form1':
            form = EmailSubscriptionForm(request.POST)
        elif form_id == 'form2':
            form = EmailSubscriptionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Thank you for subscribing with email: {email} ({form_id.capitalize()})')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Form {form_id.capitalize()} is not valid.')

    form1 = EmailSubscriptionForm()
    form2 = EmailSubscriptionForm()

    return render(request, 'maincontent/about.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})
```

email_form_1.html

```
<form class="email-submit" id="data-form-1" method="post" action="{% url 'email-submit1' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="form1">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="{{ form.email_address.name }}" id="{{ form.email_address.id }}" required/>
    <button type="submit">
      Sign Up
    </button>
</form>
```

email_form_2.html

```
<form class="email-submit" id="data-form-2" method="post" action="{% url 'email-submit2' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="form2">
    <input type="email" id="{{ form.email_address.id }}" placeholder="Enter your email..." name="{{       form.email_address.name }}" required//>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

template.html message block

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

this is my current code i have checked everything but it still displayes that the form is not valid

i was expecting that if the user submit the form by clicking on signup button a message should be displayed displaying whether it was successful or not but the messages is always saying that the form is not valid

Comment: Both forms are in same page

Comment: Which form errors do you see when debugging the function?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> 
This is the error that's being printed in terminal

Comment: The error is fixed the name attribute wasn't matching for some reason so i just changed it to email manually